# Menu Bar not expanding on hover with overflow:hidden;

Tags: css

I am currently working on a menu bar that expands vertically upwards. When I change the overflow to visible rather than hidden, the menu expands in the correct place, however the whole menu is visible which I do not want to happen. With overflow:hidden; the menu expands but only when you hover over the partially expanded menu above where I would like it to expand. Can anyone help?

```
.HomeBottomMenu {

    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    text-align: center;
    text-align: justify;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 6em;
    z-index:9999;
}

.HomeBottomMenu ul {

    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.HomeBottomMenu ul ul {

    height: 0px;
}

.HomeBottomMenu ul ul:hover {

     height:532px;  
    -webkit-transition: height 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: height 1s ease;
    -o-transition: height 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: height 1s ease;
    transition: height 1s ease;
}


.HomeBottomMenu ul li{

    position: relative;
    line-height: 21px;
    min-width: 220px;
    text-align: center;/* Used to be left*/
    background: #424242;

}

.HomeBottomMenu ul li a{

    display: block;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular',  Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;

}
.HomeBottomMenu ul li a:hover{

    color: #fff;
    background: #25a0da;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.HomeBottomMenu ul li .dropdown{

    background: #f2f2f2;
    display: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: -0.01em;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.HomeBottomMenu ul li:hover .dropdown{

   /* Display the initial dropdown */
    display: block; 
    bottom: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: #939393;
    min-height: 50px;
}

.HomeBottomMenu ul li ul.dropdowndropdown {

    position: relative;
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    bottom:100%;
}

.HomeBottomMenu ul li ul :hover .dropdowndropdown{

    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
}

.HomeBottomMenu ul li ul.dropdowndropdown li{

    display: inline-block;
    /*Colour of level 1, level 2...*/
    background-color: rgba(0, 90, 235, 0.33);
    bottom: 100%;

}
.HomeBottomMenu ul li ul.dropdowndropdown li:hover{

   position: relative;
}

.HomeBottomMenu ul li ul.dropdowndropdown li a{

    color:#fff;
    font-size:16px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-align:center;
}

.HomeBottomMenu ul li ul .dropdowndropdown li a :hover{

    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed the following and it works now:

.HomeBottomMenu ul li .dropdown{

```
background: #f2f2f2;
position: absolute;
left: -0.01em;
overflow:hidden;
display: none;
```

}

.HomeBottomMenu ul li:hover .dropdown{

```
display: block; 
bottom: 0%;
position: absolute;
background: #939393;
min-height: 50px;
```

}